# android fragment and activity : different interface, same instance

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface

My adaptor class:

```
private CheckFavourite checkFavourite;
private ItemCLickCallback itemCLickCallback;

public void setCheckFavourite(final CheckFavourite checkFavourite){
    this.checkFavourite = checkFavourite;
}

public void setItemCLickCallback(final ItemCLickCallback itemCLickCallback){
    this.itemCLickCallback = itemCLickCallback;
}

public interface ItemCLickCallback {
    void onItemClick(int p);
    void onSecItemClick(int p);
}

boolean isFavourite = checkFavourite.getFavourite(winkel);

public interface CheckFavourite{
    boolean getFavourite(Winkel winkel);
}
```

Fragment:

```
   public class Overview extends Fragment implements Adaptor.ItemCLickCallback{

    adaptor = new Adaptor(mijnwinkels, this.getActivity());
    adaptor.setItemCLickCallback(this);
    // Code is incomplete, but this works.

   adaptor.setCheckFavourite(this.getActivity());
   // This doesn't work.
 }
```

Activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptor.CheckFavourite{


@Override
public boolean getFavourite(Winkel winkel){
    boolean isFavourite = false;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);
    isFavourite = dbHandler.isFavourite(user,winkel);
    return isFavourite;
}

}
```

My fragment implements the first interface, and my adaptor gets created in my fragment. My activity implements the second interface because I need data that is in my activity to run the function, but it's the same adaptor. How can I get this to work? This is my error:

```
Error:(60, 51) error: incompatible types: FragmentActivity cannot be converted to CheckFavourite.
```

Somehow it's randomly working now? I don't get it, but I guess it's fixed. I didn't change anything yet the code starts working, lol.

Comment: Do you have a class called `FragmentActivity`? Before calling the line that causes the error (`adaptor.setCheckFavourite(this.getActivity());`), what is your `LogCat` output for `Log.d("TAG", getActivity().getClass().getName());`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to add the cast

```
   adaptor.setCheckFavourite((Adaptor.CheckFavourite)this.getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

The code started working now. I didn't change anything, yet it's working. Pretty wierd, but I guess this wasn't a good question after all. My excuses.